# How can I download github "Pull Requests" files?

Tags: github, download

How can I download github "pull requests" files?

This [Link](https://github.com/web-project-builder/user-login-management-codeigniter-adminlte-php/pull/5/commits/cb491b77e97bf35b837cd64b7cc22d1d46583c9f)

Comment: What do you mean by "download the files"? Do you have a local copy of the Git repository? Are you trying to do a local review?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pull request is a request to merge a branch from the fork into the master branch (or, occasionally, into some other branch, potentially even in the same repo).

You can see which branch on the top of the PR in GitHub, then download or clone the branch from the forked repo.

Answer (score 1):

if the `PR` is huge, like `void-package`, `brew`, or `Linux`... you can get files without old `commits` by downloading them as a `zip` file of the last state of all files, not diffs.

- Click at the last `hash` of this `PR`

[image]

- Download as a zip file

[image]

Comment: That's not it. There's a way of downloading as a zip only the changes, not the whole repo at that stage. This is what the question is about

Comment: zip file does not contain the diff files, it contains all files in the last state only,

Comment: Of the whole repo or what you can see in the "files" section of a PR?